# Pair users randomly with each other

Tags: php, laravel

I have got all the user records using random function from user table,
Now when i loop the users and try to display,

I need the record like this:

```
user a = user b
user c = user a
user b = user c
```

I must not get this kind:

```
user a = user a
user b = user b
```

Below is my code

```
public function randomUser(){
    $userData1   = User::inRandomOrder()->orderBy('email', 'ASC')->get();
    $userData2   = User::inRandomOrder()->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
    foreach($userData1 as $key => $value ) {
        if($userData1[$key]->id != $userData2[$key]->id){
            echo $userData1[$key]->first_name.$userData1[$key]->last_name."-".$userData2[$key]->first_name.$userData2[$key]->last_name."<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Also, `orderBy()` is useless in this case and FYI `inRandomOrder()` is super slow so you might want not to use it twice. Or even once since you're getting all the users and can order them manually (depends on what exactly you're trying to achieve).

Comment: Actullay i am trying to Display user randomly assigning to another user: user a = user b,
user c = user a,
user b = user c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use some kind of algorithm here. For example, you could get all users into a collection. Then just get and remove each user from the collection using [`shift()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-shift) and/or [`pop()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-pop) methods. This is an example, modify it as you want:

```
$users1 = User::inRandomOrder()->get();
$users2 = $users1;
foreach ($users1 as $user) {
    echo $user->full_name. ' - '. $users2->pop()->full-name;
}
```

Also, to make `full_name` work, use an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) instead of concatenating two string manually each time.

Comment: ErrorException (E_NOTICE)
Undefined variable: i, I get this error

Comment: @JerinMonish use `$i = 0`, I've updated the code. As I said, it's just an example to show you one way to do that.

Comment: thank you it works but only 4 records are displaying, but in my table totally i have 8 records need to show all dynamically. Could u please update me...

Comment: @JerinMonish well, if you have 8 users, you will want to see 4 records with unique users, right? If it's not the case, then please describe what exactly you want to get.

Comment: I mean all the users must be assigned to each other dynamically without repetition.

Comment: @JerinMonish well, that's exactly what this script is doing. If you want to have 8 lines, you will have 4 repetitions, right? I mean if user 1 is already assigned in the first line to someone, you don't want to see this user again in any other line.

Comment: S you are right, Do u know Christmas Friend ? its like Gift Sharing to each other within a team, so if there are 8 members in a team those 8 members will be asked to share gift among themselves. Where they each will be given a card of their christmas friend. Did u understand ?

Comment: @JerinMonish it's like "Secret Santa" or something? I think I understand what exactly you want. Please check updated code. But you might want to modify the script anyway.

Comment: ErrorException (E_NOTICE)
Undefined variable: users2 . I get this error

Comment: @JerinMonish `$users2 = $users1`

Comment: thank you very much Alexey I got it.. And we call it as Christmas Friend so u have also taught me a new word for that "Secret Santa"....

Comment: @Barmar that's the behavior OP wants. Please read the comments. Also, you can see the original version of the code (in revisions) with 4 lines which doesn't repeat users.

Comment: I see, all those comments are from before you split into `$users1` and `$users2`.

Answer (score 1):

inRandomOrder() is super slow so you might want not to use it.
You should select your data once from DB with the help of simple query without orderBy.

- For single dimensional array:

Assign your resulted array of users in two variables.

```
$a = $b = ['user a','user b','user c'];
```

Shuffle array **$a** for random

```
shuffle($a);
```

Loop it in **do-while** loop
Shuffle array **$b** and Compare both **$a & $b** arrays by index & values

```
do{
    shuffle($b);
    $c = array_diff_assoc($a, $b);
}while(count($c)!=count($a));
```

- For multidimensional array:

Assign your resulted array of users in two variables.

```
$a = $b = [array('id' => 1, 'name' => "abc"),array('id' => 2, 'name' => "def"),array('id' => 3, 'name' => "ghi")];
```

Shuffle array **$a** for random

```
shuffle($a);
```

Function to compare multidimensional arrays

```
function arrayRecursiveDiff($aArray1, $aArray2) { 
    $aReturn = array(); 

    foreach ($aArray1 as $mKey => $mValue) { 
        if (array_key_exists($mKey, $aArray2)) { 
            if (is_array($mValue)) { 
                $aRecursiveDiff = arrayRecursiveDiff($mValue, $aArray2[$mKey]); 
                if (count($aRecursiveDiff)) { $aReturn[$mKey] = $aRecursiveDiff; } 
            } else { 
                if ($mValue != $aArray2[$mKey]) { 
                    $aReturn[$mKey] = $mValue; 
                } 
            } 
        } else { 
            $aReturn[$mKey] = $mValue; 
        } 
    }
    return $aReturn; 
}
```

Loop it in **do-while** loop
Shuffle array **$b** and Compare both **$a & $b** arrays by index & values

```
do{
    shuffle($b);
    $c = arrayRecursiveDiff($a, $b);
}while(count($c)!=count($a));
```

Both arrays will be completely different from each other. Now you can do whatever with these two arrays.